# How to display <a> tag from JavaScript in HTML by escaping characters

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I have a variable in my JavaScript, where I need to pass an anchor tag and a URL to route. But I am getting errors in my JS file and it looks like I need to escape my HTML tags, but it didn't work.

Can some one help?

```
var link = "<a href="http://localhost:3002/#/login?customerid=" >Continue</a>;
```

I tried below but it didn't work:

```
&lt;a href="http://localhost:3002/#/login?customerid=" &gt;Continue&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: You have a pair of `"` nested in a pair of `"`. One of these pairs needs to use `'`.

Answer (score 3):

`var link = '<a href="http://localhost:3002/#/login?customerid=" >Continue</a>';`

The error was because if you open a string with " you have to end it with " but your url inside href is quoted with " " so it obviously failed to make your string variable. I just quoted your string with ' and let the " for the href.

Comment: I need to pass a value for my customerid also.How can we escape that

     var link = '<a href="http://localhost:3002/#/login?customerid= "+customerid>Continue</a>;'

Comment: `'<a href="http://localhost:3002/#/login?customerid='+ yourVariableHere + '" >Continue</a>';` @mhv1269

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the line as

`var link = "<a href=\"http://localhost:3002/#/login?customerid=\" >Continue</a>";`

The reason is because Javascript thinks that the string ends at the first `"`. To prevent this, the backwards slash specifically delineates this as part of the string

However, what are you using this for in the first place? Storing HTML in strings isn't recommended.